# PHY driver linking to MAC driver in U-boot

Tags: u-boot

I have question related to PHY driver linking to MAC driver in the following scenario.

- MAC driver is registered using Driver Model(using `U_BOOT_DRIVER()` function ).  Example :
  [drivers/net/tsec.c](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/4412fd8ba2ce5945d04f4b181a96e05576c46bf2/drivers/net/tsec.c#L952)
- PHY driver is registered without using Driver Model(using
  `phy_register()` function).  Example:
  [drivers/net/phy/micrel_ksz8xxx.c](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/4412fd8ba2ce5945d04f4b181a96e05576c46bf2/drivers/net/phy/micrel_ksz8xxx.c#L225)

I need to access the PHY registers using mii or mdio utilities. In the above scenario(KSZ804 PHY sitting on MII bus of TSEC MAC), where MAC driver is using Driver Model and PHY driver is not using Driver Model, how MAC and PHY will be linked so that we can access PHY registers.

Comment: Please, use the driver model for your developments if you want to have a chance to upstream them.

Comment: PHY drivers at `drivers/net/phy` registered using `phy_register()`,which adds `phy_driver` node to `phy_drivers` linked list. PHY drivers available at  `drivers/phy` are using Driver Model. If we need to convert PHY driver to Driver model then is there any steps available to follow to move from `phy_driver` structure members[driver is using mask, features, confirm startup and probe members of phy_driver structure] to `U_BOOT_DRIVER`.`UCLASS_DRIVER(phy)` defined only id and name members. PHY uclass is still under migration to Driver Model?because `UCLASS_DRIVER(serial)` is defined more members.

Comment: Existing PHY driver(without Driver Model) registering config, startup, probe and shutdown call back functions of phy_drver structure. To convert this driver to use Driver Model, we need to register U_BOOT_DRIVER with probe and ops members of the U_BOOT_DRIVER structure. At what time probe function of U_BOOT_DRIVER will be called? I mean we can move the functionality of existing PHY driver(without Driver Model) phy_driver’s probe function as it is to U-BOOT_DRIVER’s probe function?, remaining functions of phy_driver's can be used in ops member of U_BOOT_DRIVER.